Google Cloud max instance is not changing
gcloud functions deploy $FUNCTION_NAME   --gen2   --runtime nodejs20   --entry-point $FUNCTION_NAME   --source .   --region $REGION   --trigger-bucket $BUCKET   --trigger-location $REGION   --max-instances 2

I ran this command to create a function and it ran successfully but the max instance is still set to 5 though its set to 2 in the above command.
I also tried creating it manually using GUI but still same issue, its just not changing but automatically populated to 5.
Please someone help!!
I tried creating the function using cli and gui both but its not helping.

Did you check in the service value with the CLI gcloud run services describe SERVICE? Do you have any error in the logs?

Adding to what @guillaumeblaquiere mentioned. Cloud Functions gen2 (as you are stating in the flag --gen2, they underneath rely con Cloud Run. So first you can

Check the logs of the cloud run service with the same name of your function
Check the function logs

